# Cannot load gettext.so extension for php5 (cli)

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04, php-5.6, php-gettext

I'm unable to use the gettext extension with PHP-CLI.
After configuring php.ini, I get this error message whenever I use `php`:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20131226/gettext.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20131226/gettext.so: undefined symbol: PL_thr_key in Unknown on line 0

/etc/php5/cli/php.ini

> extension = gettext.so

I have both gettext and  php-gettext installed:

> gettext is already the newest version.
>
> php-gettext is already the newest version.

Yet, gettext.so seems to be missing in `/usr/lib/php5/20131226/`:

```
# ls -l

ah /usr/lib/php5/20131226/
total 488K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Mai 18 18:36 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4.0K Mär 25  2015 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  88K Mär 24  2015 curl.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  39K Sep 10  2014 json.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  47K Mär 24  2015 mcrypt.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 153K Mär 24  2015 opcache.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 116K Mär 24  2015 pdo.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  31K Mär 24  2015 readline.so
```

PHP Version:

```
$ php -v
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20131226/gettext.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20131226/gettext.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.6.7-1+deb.sury.org~utopic+1 (cli) (built: Mar 24 2015 11:23:10) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

What can I do to get it to work?

Comment: @olibiaz Hm, it tells me "E: Unable to locate package php5.6-common" when I try.